# How to use OnClickListener to create simple event // Changing text or Color

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

//Tell me where did I go wrong, I am trying to make an event by clicking the button to change the text

```
    val buttonMoto: Button = (findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonMoto))
    buttonMoto.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        fun OnClick(view: View){
            val textviewMoto: TextView = (findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textViewMoto))
            textviewMoto.text = "Hello World"
```

Comment: when I try to run, after it installed in my device. It crushes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create onClick, this is pretty simple with kotlin.

```
textview.onClick{   }
```

Comment: thanks bro, this works for me I guess, I mixed up java and kotlin

Comment:  rate up if you can

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use

```
if (view instanceof TextView) view.text = "Hello World";
```

Or even just

```
view.text = "Hello world";
```

Answer (score 0):

Jehad , If you are just trying to change some text on button click 
just use it like this with lambda functions

```
 findViewById<Button>(R.id.button).setOnClickListener {
        val textviewMoto = (findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textViewMoto))
        textviewMoto.text = "Hello World"
    }
```